# Google Place Autocomplete Address Form after typing 5 characters

Tags: javascript, google-maps, autocomplete, google-api, google-places-api

I am using the code taken from the Google Developer website (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform), which is indicated below. With this code, the google autocomplete address list appears below the address text-box just after typing the first character. I would like to be able to type 5 characters before the google list drops down. I look forward anyone of you could help me to get my aim. Thank you in advance!

```
// This example displays an address form, using the autocomplete feature
// of the Google Places API to help users fill in the information.

var placeSearch, autocomplete;
var componentForm = {
  street_number: 'short_name',
  route: 'long_name',
  locality: 'long_name',
  administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
  country: 'long_name',
  postal_code: 'short_name'
};

function initAutocomplete() {
  // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
  // location types.
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
      {types: ['geocode']});

  // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
  // fields in the form.
  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
}

function fillInAddress() {
  // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

  for (var component in componentForm) {
    document.getElementById(component).value = '';
    document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
  }

  // Get each component of the address from the place details
  // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
  for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
    var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
    if (componentForm[addressType]) {
      var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
      document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
    }
  }
}

// Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
// as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
function geolocate() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var geolocation = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };
      var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        center: geolocation,
        radius: position.coords.accuracy
      });
      autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use AutocompleteService. Each service call will be counted as one request. service = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
service.getQueryPredictions({ input: 'hotels near Lond' }, function(predictions, status){});  (Read more at https://blog.woosmap.com/implement-and-optimize-autocomplete-with-google-places-api). Only caveat is the return address has no zip code.

Answer (score 1):

A customer wanted to have autocompletion triggered only if more than 2 chars were entered.
I could not find an "out-of-the-box" solution (feature request opened at https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=10367 on Google Code).

Thx to Zme...@gmail.com (https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3429), I could work out following solution that fulfills the need.

```
if (1 < query.length) { // if 2 chars or more entered
                if (undefined == self.googleAutocomplete) { //... and Google Autocomplete not set yet
                    console.debug('trigger autocomplete !');
                    self.googleAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(self.HtmlElement, self.settings.google_options);
                }   
                // ! Beware : with 2 chars => we are only SETTING the autocompletion : actual suggestions will start from 3rd char...
                google.maps.event.addListener(self.googleAutocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
                    // do whatever with suggestion selected...
                }
            } else if (undefined != self.googleAutocomplete) { // if less than 2 chars
                    console.debug('unbind autocomplete !');
                    // removing autocompletion : Thx to Zme...@gmail.com 
                    //... on https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3429
                    $(".pac-container").remove();
                    google.maps.event.clearListeners(self.HtmlElement);
                    self.googleAutocomplete = undefined;
            }
```

Although it worked for me, I still think it is a shame to go through such heavy object instanciation/deletion just to activate/disactivate autocompletion.
Do not hesitate to vote in favor of having such a feature implemented in Google Autocompletion Api at https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=10367, if you deem it usefull.

Have a good day

Answer (score 0):

```
https://code.google.com/p/geo-autocomplete/
```

It's a jqueryplugin with some features like minlength

I vl see the plugin code and try to find out how plugin does this

here's a demo with min length 3

```
http://geo-autocomplete.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demo/ui.demo.html
```

Comment: `
var options = {
            types: ['(cities)'],
            componentRestrictions: {
                country: 'fr',
                offset:4
            }
        };
`
I tried this , It filters by country but offset doesn't work , seems like it's not supported yet in 3.exp version 

need a bounty on this i guess

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried with offset and it doesn´t work :(

Comment: That isn't what offset does at all, look at the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete): `For example, if the input term is 'Google abc' and the offset is 3, the service will attempt to match against 'Goo abc'`

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I know that you can have that kind of fine grain control over the search is to use Google's AutocompleteService where you call the query when you are ready.

This is a [sample code](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-queryprediction) at Google.  The drawback of this method is that you have to build the **input** parameter by listening to the keystrokes, as well as handle the placement of the pac-container, or whatever container you wish to use for the results on the screen, *and* a click listener, when the user clicks on a selection, which the Autocomplete call normally handles for you.

Answer (score 0):

After my client got billed for over 100,000 places API calls I was asked to start autocompleting after 3 letters typed. initialising the map by adding an event listener worked well for me! I couldnt find an easy way to do this, so adding it here to hope it can help others...using jQuery here for the custom stuff

```
<script>
function initialiseApi(){
  const myInput = document.getElementById('myInput');
  const options = {
   types: []
   };
   const autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
     myInput, options
   );
 }
    
 function initMap() {
   //initialise API if length of input >= 2 letters so autocomplete will start on 3 letters
   $('#myInput').on('input', function(){
     if( $('#myInput').val().length >= 2 ){
       //remove event listener from the input
       $('#myInput').off();
       //fire up the Google juice
       initialiseApi();
     }
   });
}
</script>

<script async src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXXXXX&libraries=places&callback=initMap"></script>
```